# Giving a Group it's own calendar

Tags: views, 7, organic-groups, datetime

I've learned how to create groups via Organic Groups, and I learned how to use the Calendar to create a site wide calendar.

I guess what I need help with now is how to integrate the two. I can't seem to figure it out. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a relationship with the group Id and set the default value of your contextual filter to group Id from content